# Default value as display value c#

Tags: json

I am getting products in JSON format and I want that my default product have a MARK that I know that is default:

```
DisplayValue = "MARK";
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can *add* a property to any object just by assigning a value:

```
var products = [{ Name: 'A' }, { Name: 'B' }, { Name: 'C' }];

$(products).each(function() {
    this.DisplayValue = "MARK" + this.Name;
}
```

Comment: can I do it for all products ...if I have it 150 or more

Comment: I need DisplayValue = "MARK+ product name";